# LINQ verify row of dates and their values

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have data in database that looks like this:

```
2017-09-01 | values A
2017-09-01 | values B
```

And I want to find out, which date does not have right count of values. So I've used something like this for every day between range of days:

```
var days = Enumerable.Range(0, to.Subtract(from).Days + 1)
    .Select(d => from.AddDays(d));

return days.ToDictionary(key => key,
    value => metricsService.View(DbContext).Count(m => value.Equals(m.Date)) == recordsCountInOneDay);
```

That works fine, but now I would like to determine which record is oldest (in continual row of days) with no data or data that does not match given criteria.

So basically:

```
2017-09-01 | Correct value
2017-09-01 | Correct value
2017-09-02 | Correct value
2017-09-04 | Correct value
```

Will return `2017-09-03` and

```
2017-09-01 | Correct value
2017-09-01 | Correct value
2017-09-02 | Wrong value
2017-09-04 | Correct value
```

Will return `2017-09-02`.

I know that I can do that with simple for loop with all days, but that is expensive because I have for each day 66 records and I want to check data for ~2 years.

Edit: To sum up I want the oldest day that is either missing or has less than 66 rows.

Comment: So, what if you had the correct value and the wrong value for the same day?

Comment: Actually, there are 66 records for one day and if there are not I consider this as not correct value. So `DbContext.Metrics.Where(x => x.Date.Equals(checkeddate)).Count() == correctCount` would return `true` if the values are there and `false` if not.

Comment: So you want the oldest day that is either missing or has less than 66 rows?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: The efficiency of for loops is no worse than linq.  Linq can even be worse.  Use code that is easy to understand and debug.  Don't create complicated linq statements that will take hours to change when you look at it 6 months from now.

Comment: `for` loop in an ordered list, with a `break` when you find what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
IEnumerble<DateTimeOffset> DaySequence(source DateTimeOffset)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return source;
        source = source.AddDays(1.0D);
    }
}

...

var from = //The start date of the comparison;

var source = metricsService.View(DbContext)
        .Where(d => d.Date >= from) // everything after start
        .GroupBy(d => d.Date) // group by Day
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key); // order by Day

var earliestFail = DaySequence(from)
    .Zip(
        source,
        (day, group) =>
            new
            {
                day,
                valid = day.Equals(group.Key) && group.Count = 66
            })
    .FirstOrDefault(a => !a.valid)
    .Select(a => a.day);
```